# Limit function of pointwise convergence is always bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> If $\{f_n \colon [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R\}$ is a sequence of bounded functions converging pointwise to $f \colon [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$, then $f$ is bounded.

Is the statement above true? I tried to find such function but always ended up with a bounded function.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f$ be any unbounded funtion and let $f_n(x)=\min\{n,f(x)\}$.

Answer (score 4):

For $n>0$, define $f_n$ on $[a,b]$ with $f_n(x)=\dfrac 1{x-a}$ if $a+\dfrac{b-a}n\leq x\leq b$ and $0$ otherwise.

Each $f_n$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ and the sequence $(f_n)$ is converging pointwise to $f$.

You'll find that $f(a)=0$ and $f(x)=\dfrac 1{x-a}$ if $a<x\leq b$, so $f$ is unbounded.

Comment: Even though the problem statement didn't require it, the $f_n$ (but not their pointwise limit) can easily be made continuous.